# What shape has the least perimeter for a given area

Tags: geometry

I’ve been considering the following question recently: of all shapes, which shape has the least perimeter for a given area. Intuitively it should be a circle. I can’t think of any shape that has less perimeter than a circle when they both have the same area. However, I can’t think of any way to formalize this into a proof. Can someone point me in the right direction? Note that multivariable calculus is the most advanced math I know.

Comment: Google "Dido's problem."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yours is a classic question in a subject called "calculus of variations." It's know as the "isoperimetric problem." A search on that topic will tell you a great deal, but the key ideas are

(1) if you don't want to be TOO careful about fiddly little technical conditions, you really need only your multivariable calculus, and

(2) if you *do* want to be careful about that stuff, it's pretty messy.

Closely related, with a nice classical tie-in to the story of Queen Dido, is the "didochrone problem." (See a previous answer of mine, [General question about optimization.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1358824/general-question-about-optimization), with some ramblings about the possible 
origin of the word.)